# How to delete a file with size 0

Tags: android, file, ddms

I'm working on a project that deals with files and I had difficult time trying to delete a file. Luckily, it was working and it still works for me.

The problem I had was I was trying to delete a file that is empty:

```
file.length()==0
```

So I solved my problem but I'm still left with a question.

`file.length()` returns 0 in both cases

1. The size is actually zero
2. The `file` does not exist in the path

So How am i supposed to eliminate the files that have 0 size in my file explorer. I have too many files with size 0 and I want to erase them from my `/files/`.

Yes, I tried selecting on the file and clicking on red X several times, but I guess eclipse does not read file with 0 size. With AVD, I could make a new AVD and launch it with formatted setting, but in real life, you can't just buy a new phone to get rid of files with size 0.

Help me how to do this on ECLIPSE please

Thank you

Comment: sometimes there are lock files with size 0 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start adb consol and write follwing command

> adb shell
>   su
>   $rm /yourpath/to/yourfilename

delete your o size file.

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish between a file that does not exist and an empty file by using

```
if (file.exists() && file.length() == 0) {
    // existing, empty file
} else {
    // file does not exist or exists and is not empty
}
```

You might also find the methods `File.isFile()` and `File.isDirectory()` useful.

Comment: file.exists returns false when the file actually exists but the size is zero

Answer (score 0):

In your code you should first create a file object and then check if it exists before trying to delete it:

```
File myFile = new File(path); // path is the absolute path of the file that you want to delete
if (myFile.exists()){   
    // Delete
    boolean deletedFile = myFile.delete();
    // Check if the file was deleted
    if(deletedFile){
        // Delete successful                
    }
    else{
        // Error                
    }
}
```